# How to shrink a database in MS SQL Server if the drive is full?

Tags: sql-server

I am having issue with SQL Server where I Can't execute any queried because the Hard Drive that hosts the databases is full. 
I tried to shrink the database using the "Shrink" function in MS SMS but that did not work because the disk space is full.

How can I truncate the logs without crashing the database but also shrink the size?

I tried the following also

```
USE myDatabaseName;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE myDatabaseName
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (myDatabaseName_Log, 1);
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE myDatabaseName
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

but got the following error

```
Msg 3023, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Backup and file manipulation operations (such as ALTER DATABASE ADD FILE) on a database must be serialized. Reissue the statement after the current backup or file manipulation operation is completed.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

Thanks

Comment: Based on the error message it sounds like you're in the middle of a backup transaction (this includes `BACKUP LOG`)?

Comment: Run `EXEC sp_who2 'active'` and see if you can spot anything backup related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### SQL Server Pre 2012

```
BACKUP LOG LogName
  WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY;
```

### SQL Server 2012 onwards

The `WITH_TRUNCATEONLY` has been removed so you should switch the recovery model to Simple and revert to perform the same action.

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
  SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

***After which, don't forget to re-instate your original recovery model!***

### Shrinking the log

Just because you've truncated the log this does not mean that the file size on disk has changed.

To reduce the file size of the log you need to issue the following command

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (DatabaseLogLogicalName, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
BACKUP LOG WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

Long answer: Backup your DB and read this first:

[Managing Transaction Logs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/64582/)

Comment: As an aside: `WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY` has been removed in SQL Server 2012. The suggestion is to switch recovery model to Simple and revert in order to perform a similar action.

Comment: Oh, and simply truncating the log will **not** clear disk space. Once you've truncated the log you need to use [`DBCC SHRINKFILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) to regain the disk space.

Comment: @gvee can you please read my question I just updated it with an error that I got by following the idea you provide. Can you please tell me what I did wrong there?

Comment: did you waited the previous command to finish before issuing the next command or you just tried to run all commands at once? Its sounds like you tried to run a backup command while the DB is already running a backup.

Comment: I just figured out the issue. there was a process that is doing a backup. so I had to kill it in order to execute this and it finally worked. If you post an answer with your solution I will mark it correct.  thanks